# How to deduce cosine theorem with vector?

Tags: geometry, vector-calculus, theorem-proving

I want to prove the cosine theorem of triangles with vectors under the following assumptions:

```
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
c = {x3, y3, z3};
θ = VectorAngle[a, b];
```

I want to get the following results：

```
(Norm[c])^2==(Norm[a])^2+(Norm[b])^2-2*(Norm[a])*(Norm[b])*Cos[θ]
```

However,

```
Clear[a, b, c, θ];
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
c = {x3, y3, z3};
θ = VectorAngle[a, b];
Reduce[c == a - b, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, θ}]

（*x3 == x1 - x2 && y3 == y1 - y2 && z3 == z1 - z2*）
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[θ]
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
c = {x3, y3, z3};

simplify = Simplify[#, {a, b, c} ∈ Reals] &;

eqn = {c, \[ScriptA], \[ScriptB], \[ScriptC], θ} == 
   simplify@{a - b, Norm@a, Norm@b, Norm@c, VectorAngle[a, b]} // Thread    

mid = Eliminate[Flatten@eqn, {c, x1, x2, y1} // Flatten] // simplify
(* 4 \[ScriptA]^2 \[ScriptB]^2 Cos[θ]^2 == 
   (\[ScriptA]^2 + \[ScriptB]^2 - \[ScriptC]^2)^2 *)
```

[image]

(Pretend not to be aware of cosine theroem) It's clear `mid` can be simplified further, but should it be

```
rst1 = 2 \[ScriptA] \[ScriptB] Cos[θ] == 
   \[ScriptA]^2 + \[ScriptB]^2 - \[ScriptC]^2
```

or

```
rst2 = - 2 \[ScriptA] \[ScriptB] Cos[θ] == 
   \[ScriptA]^2 + \[ScriptB]^2 - \[ScriptC]^2
```

? This can be checked with

```
{rst1, rst2} //. Rule @@@ Flatten[Thread /@ eqn] // 
  Simplify[#, {Norm@a > 0, Norm@b > 0, {a, b} ∈ Reals}] & // AbsoluteTiming
(* {41.5776, {True, x1 x2 + y1 y2 + z1 z2 == 0}} *)
```

So `rst1` i.e. $2 \mathit{a} \mathit{b} \cos (\theta )=\mathit{a}^2+\mathit{b}^2-\mathit{c}^2$ is generally correct, `rst2` is correct only if `a` and `b` are perpendicular.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce` can prove the cosine theorem but can not find the cosine theorem.

```
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
c = {x3, y3, z3};
Reduce[(a - b) . (a - b) == 
  a . a + b . b - 
   2 Sqrt[a . a] Sqrt[b . b] Cos[VectorAngle[a, b]], Reals]
Reduce[Norm[a - b]^2 == 
  Norm[a]^2 + Norm[b]^2 - 
   2 Norm[a] Norm[b] Cos[VectorAngle[a, b]], Reals]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to deduce the results? "Solve"?@cvgmt